# Access to RegExp using JSFuck convention

Tags: javascript, regex, jsfuck

I want to replace some characters in string e.g.

```js
console.log( 
    "truefalse".replace("e","E")
)
```

but using [jsfuck](https://kamil-kielczewski.github.io/jsfuck/index.html) convenction where only 6 chars are allowed: `[]()!+`, here for increase readability also JS strings with letters a-z and A-Z and numbers 0-9 are allowed (because it is easy to convert such strings to 6-char jsf code). So I can write it as follows

```js
console.log(
  "truefalse"["replace"]("e","E")
)
```

but in above code I use forbidden character - comma: `,`. So I use technique of calling function with 2 (and more) paremeters discovered by [trincot here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63604570/860099) as follows

```js
console.log(
  "truefalse"["split"]()["concat"]([["e"]["concat"]("E")])
    ["reduce"](""["replace"]["apply"]["bind"](""["replace"]))
)
```

Now I want to use regular expression in replace function and write code using above restrictions

```js
console.log(
  "truefalse"["replace"](/e/g,"E")
)
```

but I don't know what to do with regexp part `/e/g` ?. It is possible to do it without using any kind of 'eval' (where string is interpreted as code)?

Comment: `new RegExp('e', 'g')`

Comment: @Barmar - but how to run it using 6 chars []()!+ and strings  ? Such code `"truefalse"["replace"]("new RegExp('e', 'g')","E")` will not work. This one  `"truefalse"["replace"](new RegExp('e', 'g'),"E")` is forbidden (letters can be used only in valid JS strings)

Comment: If you are only looking for regex because of the `g` flag, there is now `replaceAll` where you can pass "e" and it will replace all of them.

Comment: @trincot regexp is needed because I also want to use following method `.match(/..../g)` (to split characters to 4-char chunks... may be it is not possible

Comment: That you could achieve with `[].constructor.from("abcdefghijkl".matchAll("...."))` because the argument is cast to a regex. You'd need to just chain a `.flat()` to it though.

Comment: @trincot this string inside matchAll is "parsed" as regexp? If yes then create answer - I will give you at least +1

Comment: I will not be able to benefit from a +1 today as I maxed out for today ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to get access to the `RegExp` constructor without evaluating code, like with the `Function` constructor:

```
""["replace"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()
```

But consider this

- If you need to replace multiple occurrences, you can use the `replaceAll` method with a string for first argument
- The methods `match` and `matchAll` can be used with a string argument, and a `RegExp` object will be created for that string on the fly, as if you had called `.match(RegExp(str))`

So if for instance you need to split a string in chunks of four characters, you can use `.matchAll("....")`. There is just two things to do more:

- As `matchAll` returns an iterator, you need to make an array from it; like with `Array.from`.
- As you don't have direct access to the `Array` variable, you could use `[].constructor` instead.
- The returned chunks are in a nested array, which needs flattening. You could chain a `.flat()` call for that.

So that becomes

```js
console.log(
  []["constructor"]["from"]("abcdefghijkl"["matchAll"]("...."))["flat"]()
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it is helpful. I thought that It can be problem with it. As addition I say that `"truefalse"["replace"](/e/g,"E")` for simple patterns can be replaced by `"truefalse"["split"]("e")["join"]("E")`

Comment: Addition2: Your eval like version can be shorted to `[]["fill"]["constructor"]("return this")()["RegExp"]("e","g")` (which produce shorter jsf code)

Comment: Indeed, and you can evaluate `"return RegExp"`.

Comment: may be this question also will be interesting for you - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63618313/860099)

Comment: thank you for your all answers :) - they helps me a lot with work on this jsf parser which produce very [small-jsfuck](https://github.com/kamil-kielczewski/small-jsfuck) code (old parsers create output houndred/thousands bigger than input - this one create only ~24x greater code + constant ~23kB bootstrap)