# Pass function with one argument to array.map using jsfuck

Tags: javascript, jsfuck

I want to convert following code (ignore console.log) to [jsfuck](https://kamil-kielczewski.github.io/jsfuck/index.html) convention where only characters `[]()!+` are allowed (but here for clarity also numbers and strings with a-Z and 0-9 chars are allowed (wrapped by double quotes) - because conversion such strings/numbers to `[]()!+` is easy)

```js
console.log(
    [1,2,3,4,5].map(x=>x**2)
)
```

After partial conversion I have

```js
console.log(
    [1,2,3,4,5]["map"]([]["fill"]["constructor"]("return(2)"))
)
```

The problem is that I'm unable to pass argument `x` into map function.

**Question**: How to convert function `x=>x**2` to jsf and pass it as `map` argument?

(I don't want to use 'eval' like solutions where we put `map` inside string which will be executed as code e.g. `[]["fill"]["constructor"]('return [1,2,3,4,5].map(x=>x**2)')()` - this is forbidden)

Comment: Apparently you do accept eval-like solutions though ;-)

Comment: @trincot if you are able to provide not-eval solution - then I will change accepted answer (which I usually not do, but in this case such solution will rule the game)

Comment: I doubt I can. I broke my head over it in the past hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function constructor takes more than one argument:

```
 []["fill"]["constructor"]('x', 'return x ** 2;')
```

Comment: Wow - so easy - I'm surprised - and this also works for multi-arguments like `[]["fill"]["constructor"]('x','y','return x*y')(3,4)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution - it also allows to define multi-arg methods

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3,4,5].map( 
    []["fill"]["constructor"]('return x=>x**2')()
  )
)
```