# Alternative way to get "C" letter in jsfuck

Tags: javascript, jsfuck

Currently [jsfuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) use following code to get "C" character

```js
console.log(
    Function("return escape")()(("")["italics"]())[2],
)
   
console.log(  // after expansion
    []["flat"]["constructor"]("return escape")()(([]+[])["italics"]())[!![]+!![]]
)

console.log(  // after final strings expansion we get pure jsfuck code
    [][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]])()(([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[!![]+!![]]
)
```

But this method use deprecated function `"".italics` [(info here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/italics). I develop little [tool](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/6mw3eL4g/) and try to find some alternative based on `btoa` but I saddly discovered that this is not supported by node.js ([online](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs))

```js
console.log(
  Function("return btoa")()("t.")[1]
)

console.log( // after expansion
  []["flat"]["constructor"]("return btoa")()("t.")[+!![]]
)

console.log( // after full expansion
  [][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([][[]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+![])[+!![]])()([]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]])[+!![]]
)
```

Is there a way (working on current versions of chrome, safari, firefox and node.js) to get character "C" using jsfuck but without using deprecated methods?

## UPDATE 2022

According to [this comment](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/issues/122#issuecomment-1165407391) and [this doc](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#btoadata) `btoa` is supported by node-js at least in version 17 - this allow to use short (and more trivial) solutions (one is given in this question - in above snippet) (you can check this online [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online/))

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(67)`?

Comment: @JanStránský that method contains two letters `C` in its name - and actually other letters of method can be achieved without using deprecated functions

Comment: Sorry, I meant `String.fromCharCode(67)` translated to jsfuck. Shows me 12531-long code

Comment: @JanStránský no because  that standard jsfuck code will execute "italics" inside (to get letter "C") - which is forbidden

Comment: `escape` is also not far from getting deprecated.

Comment: `decodeURI("%43")` returns "C", though I've probably misunderstood something.

Comment: Or "\x43"...... Depends on which characters you already got covered.

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce [here](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/jsfuck.js) you need letter R, it is produced from RegExp, but to get regexp we need slash `/` but to get slash again `italics` is used - however may be you found alternative way to get R

Comment: @trincot [here](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/jsfuck.js) formula for backslash  is not given so I guess we need String.fromCharCode to get it (but may be I'm wrong... ?)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Backslash requires `RegExp` too, no? Line 103

Comment: If different code based on environment is OK, `atob("Qw==")` works on browsers and `Buffer.from("Qw==","base64").toString()` on node.js . EDIT: "based on environment" = based on if `global.atob` or `global.Buffer` is `undefined` or defined

Comment: This is far-fetched, but could throwing a deliberate ReferenceError, and doing ReferenceError.toString()[0] work to produce "R"? EG: `try{nonexistentvariable}catch(e){e.toString()[0]}`

Comment: Is this correct ? `Function("return escape")()(("")["fontcolor"]([0]+false))[2]`

Comment: @Carlos1232 according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor): no

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce I think you are close

Comment: @trincot after long meditation I nice found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850312/860099)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fact that `escape` is semi-deprecated kept bothering me, so I took another stab at it. Let's rebuild JSFuck from scratch.

## Level 0

You can get the following values as primitives:

```
false           ![]
true            !![]
undefined       [][[]]
NaN             +[![]]
""              []+[]
0               +[]
1               +!+[]
2               +!+[]+!+[]
3               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
4               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
5               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
6               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
7               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
8               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
9               +!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
```

## Level 1

With the above values and the fact that `value+[]` converts to string, we can set up the following character substitution rules:

```
"0"             0+[]
"1"             1+[]
"2"             2+[]
"3"             3+[]
"4"             4+[]
"5"             5+[]
"6"             6+[]
"7"             7+[]
"8"             8+[]
"9"             9+[]
"a"             (false+[])[1]
"d"             (undefined+[])[2]
"e"             (true+[])[3]
"f"             (false+[])[0]
"i"             ([false]+undefined)[1+[0]]
"l"             (false+[])[2]
"n"             (undefined+[])[1]
"r"             (true+[])[1]
"s"             (false+[])[3]
"t"             (true+[])[0]
"u"             (undefined+[])[0]
"N"             (NaN+[])[0]
```

## Level 2

With the above characters, we can construct these four strings:

```
"11e100"        +!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]
"1e1000"        +!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]
"flat"          (![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]
"entries"       (true+[])[3]+(undefined+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+([false]+undefined)[1+[0]]+(true+[])[3]+(false+[])[3]
```

With which we can get three more values:

```
1.1e+101                +("11e100")
Infinity                +("1e1000")
Array Iterator          []["entries"]()
Array.prototype.flat    []["flat"]
```

The last one is particularly useful, because when converted to a string, it yields this:

```
"function flat() {\n    [native code]\n}"
```

Or this:

```
"function flat() { [native code] }"
```

This is a bit wonky to work with, but the characters up to and including the `{` are always the same, as is the last character.

`Array Iterator` will convert to something more stable:

```
"[object Array Iterator]"
```

This gives us more characters to work with:

```
" "             ([false]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]
"("             ([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]
")"             ([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]
"+"             (+("11e100")+[])[4]
"."             (+("11e100")+[])[1]
"["             ([]+[]["entries"]())[0]
"]"             ([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]
"{"             ([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]
"c"             ([]["flat"]+[])[3]
"j"             ([]+[]["entries"]())[3]
"o"             ([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]
"y"             (true+[Infinity])[1+[1]]
"A"             ([NaN]+([]+[]["entries"]()))[1+[1]]
"I"             (Infinity+[])[0]
```

## Level 3

Combining level 1 and 2 characters and values, we can now build three new strings:

```
".0000001"      (+("11e100")+[])[1]+[0]+[0]+[0]+[0]+[0]+[0]+[1]
"constructor"   ([]["flat"]+[])[3]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+(undefined+[])[1]+(false+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[0]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+(true+[])[1]
```

And this gives us access to a bunch of further values:

```
1e-7            +(".0000001")
Boolean         (![])["constructor"]
Number          (+[])["constructor"]
String          ([]+[])["constructor"]
Function        []["flat"]["constructor"]
```

By converting to strings, we get yet more characters:

```
"-"             (+(".0000001")+[])[2]
"b"             ([]+(+[])["constructor"])[1+[2]]
"g"             (false+[0]+([]+[])["constructor"])[2+[0]]
"m"             ([]+(+[])["constructor"])[1+[1]]
"B"             ([NaN]+(![])["constructor"])[1+[2]]
"F"             ([NaN]+[]["flat"]["constructor"])[1+[2]]
"S"             ([NaN]+([]+[])["constructor"])[1+[2]]
```

## Level 4

Given the uppercase `S`, we could now build the string `"toString` manually. However, if we first build the string `"name"`, we can achieve an overall shorter code:

```
"name"         (undefined+[])[1]+(false+[])[1]+([]+(+[])["constructor"])[1+[1]]+(true+[])[3]
"toString"     (true+[])[0]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+([]+[])["constructor"]["name"]
```

And with that we can call `Number.toString()`, giving us all remaining lowercase letters:

```
"h"             (+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](2+[1])[1]
"k"             (+(2+[0]))["toString"](2+[1])
"p"             (+(2+[1]+[1]))["toString"](3+[1])[1]
"q"             (+(2+[1]+[2]))["toString"](3+[1])[1]
"v"             (+(3+[1]))["toString"](3+[2])
"w"             (+(3+[2]))["toString"](3+[3])
"x"             (+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](3+[4])[1]
"z"             (+(3+[5]))["toString"](3+[6])
```

At the same time, we can construct two more strings:

```
"slice"         (false+[])[3]+(false+[])[2]+([false]+undefined)[1+[0]]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(true+[])[3]
"-1"            (+(".0000001")+[])[2]+[+!+[]]
```

And that gives us one last character that we need for the next level:

```
"}"             ([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")
```

## Level 5

At this point, there's one primitive we obtained that we haven't used yet: using `Function` as an eval primitive:

```
[]["flat"]["constructor"](...)()
```

Since we have all lowercase letter now as well as space, `+`, `.`, `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`, we can build:

```
"try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}"
```

By means of:

```
(true+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[Infinity])[1+[1]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+([]+[])["constructor"]["name"]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+(+("11e100")+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[1]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+(true+[])[1]+([]+(+[])["constructor"])[1+[1]]+(false+[])[1]+(false+[])[2]+([false]+undefined)[1+[0]]+(+(3+[5]))["toString"](3+[6])+(true+[])[3]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+![]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(false+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](2+[1])[1]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+(false+[])[0]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+(undefined+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[1]+([false]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(false+[])[0]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")
```

Calling `String.prototype.normalize()` with a value that isn't a valid Unicode Normalization Form will throw a `RangeError`, which we catch and return to the caller. We thus have:

```
RangeError      []["flat"]["constructor"]("try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}")()
```

Note that the above is an instance - we'd have to use `["constructor"]` to get the function/constructor, but we can just convert it to string as-is, giving us two more uppercase letters:

```
"E"             ([false]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}")())[1+[0]]
"R"             ([]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}")())[0]
```

## Level 6

With two more characters unlocked, we can now construct this string:

```
"return RegExp" (true+[])[1]+(true+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+(undefined+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[1]+([false]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+([]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}")())[0]+(true+[])[3]+(false+[0]+([]+[])["constructor"])[2+[0]]+([false]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("try{String().normalize(false)}catch(f){return f}")())[1+[0]]+(+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](3+[4])[1]+(+(2+[1]+[1]))["toString"](3+[1])[1]
```

And that gives us a new value/function:

```
RegExp          []["flat"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()
```

When invoked with no arguments and converting the resulting `RegExp` to string, we get:

```
"/(?:)/"        []+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()()
```

So we have a bunch of new special characters:

```
"/"             ([]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()())[0]
":"             ([]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()())[3]
"?"             ([]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]("return RegExp")()())[2]
```

## Level 7

Now we feed one of those characters back into the regex to get a new string:

```
"/\\//"         []+RegExp("/")
```

This gives us access to a single new character:

```
"\\"            ([]+RegExp("/"))[1]
```

## Level 8

Let's build a new string:

```
"try{Function([]+[[]].concat([[]]))()}catch(f){return f}"
```

By:

```
(true+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[Infinity])[1+[1]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]["name"]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+(+("11e100")+[])[4]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+(+("11e100")+[])[1]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+(undefined+[])[1]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(false+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(false+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](2+[1])[1]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+(false+[])[0]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+(undefined+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[1]+([false]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(false+[])[0]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")
```

This is equivalent to:

```
"try{Function(',')()}catch(f){return f}"
```

Except for the fact that we can't write `','` (yet). Evaluating that will return a `SyntaxError` object, which, when converted to string, will yield:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','"
```

We can then feed that string into `RegExp("[\u0027]").exec(...)[0]` to extract the single quote.
So we wanna run:

```
RegExp("[\u0027]").exec(Function("try{Function([]+[[]].concat([[]]))()}catch(f){return f}")())[0]
```

Applying a whole bunch of substitutions from above, we get one final character:

```
"'"             RegExp(([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+RegExp("/"))[1]+(undefined+[])[0]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]])[(true+[])[3]+(+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](3+[4])[1]+(true+[])[3]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]]([]["flat"]["constructor"]((true+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[Infinity])[1+[1]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+[]["flat"]["constructor"]["name"]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+(+("11e100")+[])[4]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+(+("11e100")+[])[1]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+([true]+[]["flat"])[1+[0]]+(undefined+[])[1]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(false+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[0]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["entries"]())[2+[2]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1")+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(false+[])[1]+(true+[])[0]+([]["flat"]+[])[3]+(+(1+[0]+[1]))["toString"](2+[1])[1]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[3]]+(false+[])[0]+([]+[]["flat"])[1+[4]]+([true]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(true+[])[1]+(true+[])[3]+(true+[])[0]+(undefined+[])[0]+(true+[])[1]+(undefined+[])[1]+([false]+[]["flat"])[2+[0]]+(false+[])[0]+([true]+[]["flat"])["slice"]("-1"))())[0]
```

## Level 9

At this point, we can return every character we want simply by doing:

```
Function("return '\uXXXX'")()
```

## Demo

Let's take the character `"C"` from your question:

```
Function("return '\u0043'")()
```

Running this through all the substitutions above produces an absolute nightmare of 167'060 bytes. This exceeds the maximum post length on SO, [but I pasted it into a gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Siguza/b9d8a8571542f554f3f07f5b22f46599/raw/79fe00148f9232aa699290b9abf9f5063920804f/C.jsfuck), so feel free to try it. Though you might want to run it by means other than manually pasting it into your console...

Comment: Thank you for your deep and "full" answer :) I hope that in future ESx JS standards they introduce something which will allow to get 'C' in easy way

Comment: If this is interesting for you, recently I develop tool which allow to create small js-fuck codes - look [here](https://github.com/kamil-kielczewski/small-jsfuck) (however currently it based on deprecated methods - but I work on it)

Comment: When I run that looong one from link in chrome console I get `undefined` - :P

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski What environment? I tested on Firefox, Chrome and NodeJS...

Comment: I paste it to chrome console. I also see that we can a little short you solution decode/encodeURI are not deprecated so we can write: `decodeURI(encodeURI(" ")[0]+"43")` where we get U from `(NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+String["name"]]["call"]())[11]` If I not miss anything

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Oh wow, neat! I was trying to scrape together `U`, `R` and `I`, but couldn't find anywhere to get the `U`. Yes, that's totally possible then. Also, I think the reason you're getting `undefined` is because the CSP for `gist.githubusercontent.com` disallows `Function()` constructor calls. In Firefox I get a diagnostic message about it, but Chrome just silently fails. If you paste it into the console on SO though, it should work.

Comment: Yes you are right - when I switch to new tab it works and return 'C' - Im surprised that pages can impose restrictions to chrome console (I don't know this). Thank you very much again for you answer - don't short it because maybe in future decodeURI will be also deprecated... :P

Comment: I discover new [trick here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63802899/860099) - may be you will be able to develop it (in another answer)?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski nice, but I don't think it merits a new answer. I mean, you can just replace my levels 5 & 6 with that.

Comment: it is actually non trivial trick which allows to avoid throwing any exception - so I think it is major improvement, worth to be in separate answer

Comment: after long meditation - I found even better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850312/860099)

Answer (score 5):

## Low-level JS solution

This is alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63802899/860099) (I use matchAll idea from there in middle step). Main idea to generate character C (and more) using char code but without using quotes - it is possible when we define object field:

```js
console.log(
  Function("return Object.entries({\\u0043:false})")()[0][0]
)
```

To transform this solution close to jsf I use following "helpers"

```js
console.log(
  // "(" left parenthesis: 
  ([]["flat"]+"")[13], 
  
  // ")" right parenthesis:
  ([0]+false+[]["flat"])[20],
  
  // "{" left brace:
  (true+[]["flat"])[20],
  
  // "}" right brace:
  ([]["flat"]+"")["slice"]("-1"),
  
  // "+" plus
  (+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[2],
  
  // "-" minus:
  (+((+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+[+[]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]],
  
  // " " space:
  (NaN+[]["flat"])[11],
  
  // "." dot:
  (+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]],
  
  // "RegExp" string: (""+"".matchAll()).split(" ")[1]
  ([]+("")["matchAll"]())["split"](" ")[1],

  // ":" - colon: (Function("return RegExp")()()+"")[3]
  ([]["flat"]["constructor"]("return "+([]+("")["matchAll"]())["split"](" ")[1])()()+[])[3],

  // "/" - slash: (Function("return RegExp")()()+"")[0]
  ([]["flat"]["constructor"]("return "+([]+("")["matchAll"]())["split"](" ")[1])()()+[])[0], 
    
  // "\" - backslash: (Function("return RegExp(RegExp()+[])")()+[])[1]
  // (Function(("return "+false+"("+false+"()+[])").split(false).join("RegExp"))()+[])[1]
  ([]["flat"]["constructor"](("return "+false+"("+false+"()+[])")["split"](false)["join"](([]+("")["matchAll"]())["split"](" ")[1]))()+[])[1],
)
```

Finally we have (after full decoding it will have ~16k jsf characters)

```js
// step 1
console.log(
  []["flat"]["constructor"]("return"+" "+"Object"+"."+"entries"+"("+"{"+"\\"+"u0043"+":"+false+"}"+")")()[0][0]
)

// step 2
console.log(
  []["flat"]["constructor"]("return"+" "+"Object"+"."+"entries"+([]["flat"]+"")[13]+(true+[]["flat"])[20]+([]["flat"]["constructor"](("return "+false+"("+false+"()+[])")["split"](false)["join"](([]+("")["matchAll"]())["split"](" ")[1]))()+[])[1]+"u0043"+":"+false+([]["flat"]+"")["slice"]("-1")+([0]+false+[]["flat"])[20])()[0][0]
)
```

Doing this we stay at level 3 according to [Siguza answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713987/860099)

Comment: Okay WOW. I did _not_ expect `{\u0043:false}` to be valid JavaScript.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here I develop [Siguza answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713987/860099) if we use non deprecated de/encodeURI (level 5) we have

```js
console.log(
  decodeURI(encodeURI(" ")[0]+"43"),
  (NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+String["name"]]["call"]())[11] // here is for U came from
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire approach depends on `escape("<")`, which yields `"%3C"`. We can easily substitute that with `escape(",")`, which gives us `"%2C"`. JSFuck already has a way to obtain `","`: `[[]]["concat"]([[]])+[]`

```
escape(",")[2]
```

becomes

```
Function("return escape")()(",")[2]
```

becomes

```
[]["flat"]["constructor"]("return escape")()([[]]["concat"]([[]])+[])[2]
```

becomes

```
[]["f"+"l"+"a"+"t"]["c"+"o"+"n"+"s"+"t"+"r"+"u"+"c"+"t"+"o"+"r"]("r"+"e"+"t"+"u"+"r"+"n"+" "+"e"+"s"+"c"+"a"+"p"+"e")()([[]]["c"+"o"+"n"+"c"+"a"+"t"]([[]])+[])[2]
```

becomes

```
[][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]][([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]](([]+!![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([]+[][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+(+([]+(+!+[]+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])))[([]+!+[])[+[]]+([]+[][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+([]+[])[([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!+[])[+[]]+([]+!+[])[+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([]+([]+[])[([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+!+[]]])[[]+(+!+[])+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[])]]([]+(+!+[]+!+[]+!+[])+(+!+[]))[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([[]][([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!+[]]+([][([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+![])[+!+[]]+([]+!![])[+[]]]([[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]
```

I did this manually though, so it may not be the optimal/shortest representation.

Comment: Escape is deprecated though, isn't it?

Comment: It is not deprecated [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

Comment: @Siguza - Great answer - you save jsfuck :) - I will accept this answer - however escape is "partially" deprecated - so if someone in the future give solution which will be fully non-deprecated then I will switch and accept that person answer. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

This is development of my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746618/860099) - here is the TRICK which allows to get string `RegExp` (but we use letter R here) without throwing any exception (!) - (so we are in level 4 according to [Siguza noation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713987/860099))

```js
// TRICK:
console.log(
  (""+"".matchAll(""))   // 1. this gives "...RegExp..."
)


// encode/decode URI strings
console.log(
  "encode"+(NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+String["name"]]["call"]())[11]+(NaN+""["matchAll"](""))[11]+([]+(+"1e1000"))[0],
  
  "decode"+(NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+String["name"]]["call"]())[11]+(NaN+""["matchAll"](""))[11]+([]+(+"1e1000"))[0]
)



// Final formula
console.log(
  decodeURI(encodeURI(" ")[0]+"43")
)
```

And expnded  final formula

```js
// JSF (with allowed strings and numbers and NaN)
console.log(
  []["flat"]["constructor"]("return "+"decode"+(NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+([]+[])["constructor"]["name"]]["call"]())[11]+(NaN+""["matchAll"](""))[11]+([]+(+"1e1000"))[0])()([]["flat"]["constructor"]("return "+"encode"+(NaN+[]["entries"]()["to"+([]+[])["constructor"]["name"]]["call"]())[11]+(NaN+""["matchAll"](""))[11]+([]+(+"1e1000"))[0])()((NaN+[]["flat"])[11])[0]+43)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses Base64 encoding to get the letter `C`. Keep note that `C` in Base64 represents the bits `000010`.

Let's look at a run of 3 bytes that are being encoded in base64. We're going to call these 3 bytes `data`.

```
data = [aaaaaabb bbbbcccc ccdddddd]
              ^-----^
```

We're going to focus on the 2nd Base64 character in this run. To get it to be `C`, the low 2 bits of `data[0]` must be `00` and the high 4 bits of `data[1]` must be `0010`. We can achieve this using the string `'0 '`:

```
'0' -> 0b00110000
' ' -> 0b00100000

data = [00110000 00100000 xxxxxxxx]
              ^-----^
```

*Note: I chose `"0 "` because it was achievable with the least amount of characters. There are plenty of other pairs of characters that could achieve a similar result.*

And voilà! There's our solution. Now, we simply have to JSF*ck-ify this:

```js
btoa("0 ")[1]
// Replace btoa with an arbitrary function
Function("return btoa")()("0 ")[1]
```

Here's how that is rendered in its full glory:

```js
const capital_c = ([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][(([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(([])[(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[(+!![])+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]]+(([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(([])[(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[(+!![])+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([+[![]]]+([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+!+[]]]+(([])[(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[(+!![])+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(([])[(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[(+!![])+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]])()([+[]]+([+[![]]]+([])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+!+[]]])[+!+[]];
console.log(capital_c);
```

Total length: 1606 bytes

Comment: your solution based on `btoa("0 ")` is longer than solution based on `btoa("t.")` given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63673610/860099) few years ago